# Call multiple time kubernetes api

Tags: docker, api, rest, kubernetes

I'm using api python kuberntes and call `read_namespaced_job_status` multiple time to get status of job.

However, approximately in **250 times** to called the api, appears the follow message

```
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Sun, 25 Jul 2021 12:27:11 GMT', 'Content-Length': '129'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
```

```
def status(job_name):
    status = None

    try:
        while status != 1:
            api_response = batch_v1.read_namespaced_job_status(name=job_name, namespace=namespace)
            status = api_response.status.succeeded
            print(f'status -- {status} of job -----> {job_name} ')
            time.sleep(10)
    except Exception as error:
        print(f'error on thread --> {error}')
```

Answer (score 0):

How you are authenticating the script using the SA or ?

```
# If running inside pod
config.load_incluster_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
v1ext = client.ExtensionsV1beta1Api() 

w = watch.Watch()

mydict={}

webhook_url = '';

while True:
    pod_list= v1.list_namespaced_pod("default");
    for i in pod_list.items:
        for c in i.status.container_statuses:
            if(c.ready == True):
                if i.metadata.name in mydict:
                    print("Inside mydict If");
                    print("Pod updated : ",i.metadata.name);
                    print("My dict value : ",mydict);
                    mydict[i.metadata.name]['end_time'] = i.status.conditions[1].last_transition_time;
```

i am using this way never faced issue if your script is running inside the POD.

```
config.load_incluster_config()
```

however you can also check out the auth : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/

Which specific auth method are you using also check if there is any firewall or rate limiting configured or not.

i have not faced issue with the static token method : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#static-token-file

Comment: i'm using this way - config.load_kube_config(), batch_v1 = client.BatchV1Api(). we access by edge machine the cluster

Comment: I'm using token and probably it lost the credentiais. how to increase numbers of requests ?